# Why do nping packets with correct MAC and wrong IP do not reach the other container on the same net?

Tags: linux, networking, docker, icmp

I have a Docker network with two containers in it. When I run `nping` with a fake target IP address and a real MAC address of the second container, the packets appear in the `tcpdump -eni eth0` output with a different source addresses (both MAC and IP) and with a substantial delay (~10s).

Is it a Docker bug, or am I missing something?

---

Here is how you can reproduce the issue.

Run this script:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=10.16.17.0/24 so_con

docker run -itd --name=con_A --net=so_con debian /bin/bash
docker run -itd --name=con_B --net=so_con debian /bin/bash

docker exec con_A sh -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y tcpdump'
docker exec con_B sh -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y nmap'

export A_MAC=`docker inspect -f '{{.NetworkSettings.Networks.so_con.MacAddress}}' con_A`

docker exec con_B nping -c 100 --rate 1 --dest-mac $A_MAC 2.15.9.20 &
docker exec con_A tcpdump -eni eth0
```

After the `apt-get` finishes installing packets, you will see intermingled output from `nping` and `tcpdump`:

```
Starting Nping 0.6.47 ( http://nmap.org/nping ) at 2016-01-07 16:35 UTC
SENT (0.0331s) ICMP [10.16.17.3 > 2.15.9.20 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=6585 seq=1] IP [ttl=64 id=3571 iplen=28 ]
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
SENT (1.0336s) ICMP [10.16.17.3 > 2.15.9.20 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=6585 seq=3] IP [ttl=64 id=3571 iplen=28 ]
SENT (2.0351s) ICMP [10.16.17.3 > 2.15.9.20 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=6585 seq=3] IP [ttl=64 id=3571 iplen=28 ]
SENT (3.0366s) ICMP [10.16.17.3 > 2.15.9.20 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=6585 seq=4] IP [ttl=64 id=3571 iplen=28 ]
SENT (4.0381s) ICMP [10.16.17.3 > 2.15.9.20 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=6585 seq=5] IP [ttl=64 id=3571 iplen=28 ]
SENT (5.0396s) ICMP [10.16.17.3 > 2.15.9.20 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=6585 seq=6] IP [ttl=64 id=3571 iplen=28 ]
SENT (6.0410s) ICMP [10.16.17.3 > 2.15.9.20 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=6585 seq=7] IP [ttl=64 id=3571 iplen=28 ]
SENT (7.0419s) ICMP [10.16.17.3 > 2.15.9.20 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=6585 seq=8] IP [ttl=64 id=3571 iplen=28 ]
SENT (8.0433s) ICMP [10.16.17.3 > 2.15.9.20 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=6585 seq=9] IP [ttl=64 id=3571 iplen=28 ]
SENT (9.0447s) ICMP [10.16.17.3 > 2.15.9.20 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=6585 seq=10] IP [ttl=64 id=3571 iplen=28 ]
16:36:00.699670 02:42:0a:10:11:03 > 02:42:0a:10:11:02, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 42: 10.16.17.1 > 2.15.9.20: ICMP echo request, id 6585, seq 3, length 8
16:36:00.699764 02:42:0a:10:11:02 > 02:42:1b:a1:db:5a, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 70: 10.16.17.2 > 10.16.17.1: ICMP redirect 2.15.9.20 to host 10.16.17.1, length 36
16:36:00.699809 02:42:0a:10:11:02 > 02:42:1b:a1:db:5a, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 42: 10.16.17.1 > 2.15.9.20: ICMP echo request, id 6585, seq 3, length 8
16:36:01.701244 02:42:0a:10:11:03 > 02:42:0a:10:11:02, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 42: 10.16.17.1 > 2.15.9.20: ICMP echo request, id 6585, seq 3, length 8
```

Two observations here:

1. `tcpdump` receives first package only after some time (9s).
2. The received package comes from the Docker special bridge interface, that is attached to the host, in my case it is:

   ```
   br-436234216b46 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:1b:a1:db:5a  
         inet addr:10.16.17.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
   ```

Also, if you run `tcpdump` at the mentioned host-binded interface `br-436234216b46`, it will show the original `nping` packages coming from `con_B` by some reason to it, instead of `con_A`.

I use *Docker* `1.9.1` on 64 bit *Ubuntu* `14.04`.

Comment: The intermingled output is confusing. What were the actual commands you ran, with their actual output?

Comment: @HenryTK, I ran the script embedded into the question, and the actual output is long so I included only the relevant piece. but here it is in full: https://gist.github.com/necto/782f961be33feae10f8f